# How do I call another task in Rake

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rake

Although this might sound similar to the other questions you find here, there is a slight twist. I have two directories, say /home/rails/Rake and /home/rails/test_app. The rails directory is where I place all my rails projects.

Inside Rake, I have a *Rakefile* and a *create.rake* file.

This is what my *rakefile* look's like

```
namespace :setup do 
    desc "something"
    task :init do
        print "Name of the destination directory: "
        name = STDIN.gets.strip
        cp_r '.', "../#{name}/lib/tasks"
        cd  "../#{name}"
        sh "rake setup:create"

    end
end
```

And *create.rake*

```
namespace :setup do 
    desc "Install"
    task :create do
        sh 'git init'
        #some other code
    end
end
```

What it does is obvious. I want to copy the contents of the Rake directory to /test_app/lib/tasks. Then change directory to test_app and run setup:create task defined in the install.rake file now placed in test_app/lib/tasks. This works, but is this the rake way of doing  it? Can anyone give me a slight hint of how it's done, the Rake way.

Here is the error which I get when I used invoke method:

```
$ rake setup:init
Name of the destination directory: 
testapp
cp -r . ../testapp/lib/tasks
cd ../testapp
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'setup:create'
/home/TradeRaider/rails/Rake/Rakefile:8:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/TradeRaider/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/home/TradeRaider/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => setup:init
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This is more rake-ish :)

```
 Rake::Task["setup:create"].invoke
```

Comment: I actually tried it, but it doesn't seem to work in my case. Initially, when I call rake setup:init, it fetches the ~/rails/Rake/Rakefile and executes the init task. If setup:create was defined in the same file, I could have used invoke method. But I am trying to call a task defined in ~/rails/testapp/lib/tasks. In that case, it wouldn't work.

Comment: Or am I missing something?

Comment: I've attached it to the end of my question.

Comment: hum, did you add `require 'rake'` in your rake file?

Comment: I loaded the rake file and then did what you said. Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 5):

Although @apneadiving answer helped, it just struck me that I was trying to call a Rakefile from another Rakefile, literally speaking.  Anyways, to do so, I had to first load the rake file,

```
load "../#{name}/lib/tasks/create.rake"
```

(requiring it will also do the trick)

and then invoke it.

```
Rake::Task["setup:create"].invoke
```